# Clone a 'link' in SWT

Tags: java, hyperlink, swt, clone

I have a table of information that includes a username, an ip address, and a timestamp.

What I wanted to do was to have the ip address contained within a link object that when the link is clicked it utilizes bgp.he.net to get information about the host/IP address.  I have tried creating threads to resolve the IP addresses but it is often a large amount of IP addresses and I read that InetAddress#getByName isn't non-blocking, so I figured having links that go to this site is the next best thing.

Question is: Is it possible to have links for each of my IP addresses in the table without creating a new link object for each row?  I don't know how bad that would be on memory usage which is why I'm inquiring about cloning an instance of an IP and having the link open bgp.he.net/link.getText()

Comment: So you want to share one link object across multiple rows, but the contained IP address should be different each time?

Comment: Think of it in jquery.  You have <span class="link">http://whatever.net</span>

then you would do:
$(".link").click(function() { alert( $(this).text() ); });

Does that make more sense? There could be multiple 'span' tags with the class 'link', each containing different links.

Comment: I have no idea what that means :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Link widget in the Table, you have to use separate widget at cell location. if you have too many rows in the table obviously it will effect performance.

(1):
What you could do here is create/keep only visible number of Links and dispose remaining ( memory performance is optimized) but other side effect is you end up creating and disposing Link widgets when you scroll / resize table.

(2)
Paint your cell with url ( mimicking hyperlink)  and handle mouse event when user clicks in cell bounds. ( no need worry about paint performance, paint event will be called when required in Table).